# Draw MKPolyline Fill Color

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, polyline

I am attempting to draw a nice `MKPolyline` on an `MKPolylineView`. Everything is going great so far - the polyline draws just as I want it to and when I want it to using the following code:

```
[[self map] addOverlay:routeLine];
```

And this method to tell the app how to draw it:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;
    self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:[self routeLine]];
    [[self routeLineView] setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:167/255.0f green:210/255.0f blue:244/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [[self routeLineView] setStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:136/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    [[self routeLineView] setLineWidth:15.0];
    [[self routeLineView] setLineCap:kCGLineCapRound];
    overlayView = [self routeLineView];
    return overlayView;
}
```

As a result I get a line with a solid blue. The blue I see is not however the fill color with the stroke I am expecting - it is the blue of the stroke color. There is no fill color when I use this method. **Why doesn't it draw the fill color on the polyline?**

After investigating further, I found this tidbit of information in the *Quick Help* section of Xcode:

> The MKPolylineView class provides the visual representation for an MKPolyline annotation object. This view strokes the path represented by the annotation. (**This class does not fill the area enclosed by the path**.) You can change the color and other drawing attributes of the path by modifying the properties inherited from the MKOverlayPathView class.

That just sounds ridiculous. I have to use this class to *set* the fill color, but I can't use this class to *draw* the fill color? That just seems very odd considering it already draws the stroke. The last line in this explanation from the documentation is a little unclear but seems to provide an answer - I'm just having a hard time coding / finding the answer. I don't have an `MKOverlayPathView` in my project (what is that anyway?) but **it seems to be the solution - does anyone know how to use it?**

Comment: `MKPolylineView` is a subclass of `MKOverlayPathView`. Regardless, you just want to use `MKPolygon` (and create the associated `MKPolygonView`) instead of `MKPolyline`. `MKPolygon` draws both the stroke and the fill.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want a line of one color, and a fill of another, use a `MKPolygon` instead of a `MKPolyline`. So modify your original creation of the annotation accordingly. And then you modify your `viewForOverlay` (or, for iOS 7, `rendererForOverlay`) to recognize the `MKPolygon` and do something like the following:

```
// for iOS7+; see `viewForOverlay` for earlier versions

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];

        renderer.fillColor   = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    return nil;
}

// for iOS versions prior to 7; see `rendererForOverlay` for iOS7 and later

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView *overlayView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];

        overlayView.fillColor      = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        overlayView.strokeColor    = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        overlayView.lineWidth      = 3;

        return overlayView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Note, you don't need to reference any of your class properties here, as the overlay is passed to your `viewForOverlay`. This is a little more flexible in case you ever have multiple overlays added to your map.

---

Incidentally, these are my standard `viewForOverlay` (iOS versions prior to 7.0) and `rendererForOverlay` (iOS 7+), which will handle `MKPolygon`, `MKPolyline`, and `MKCircle` overlays:

```
// for iOS7+; see `viewForOverlay` for earlier versions

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];

        renderer.fillColor   = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]])
    {
        MKCircleRenderer *renderer = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];

        renderer.fillColor   = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        renderer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        renderer.lineWidth   = 3;

        return renderer;
    }

    return nil;
}

// for iOS versions prior to 7; see `rendererForOverlay` for iOS7 and later

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView *overlayView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];

        overlayView.fillColor      = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        overlayView.strokeColor    = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        overlayView.lineWidth      = 3;

        return overlayView;
    }

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKCircle class]])
    {
        MKCircleView *overlayView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];

        overlayView.fillColor     = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        overlayView.strokeColor   = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        overlayView.lineWidth     = 3;

        return overlayView;
    }

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]])
    {
        MKPolylineView *overlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

        overlayView.strokeColor     = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        overlayView.lineWidth       = 3;

        return overlayView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This way I can add as many of these three types of overlays to my map, and it can render all of them properly.

Comment: Polygon creates a closed shape, while polyline creates an open shape. Is it possible to do this without closing the shape? I want a line drawn, with fill and stroke, but the line closes with polygon, and has no fill with polyline..

Comment: Add two overlays, one for the fill (a polygon with no visible stroke/border, e.g. a clear `strokeColor`), and another for the open stroke (a polyline).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by implementing your own MKOverlayPathView subclass, which draws the path twice in the map rect. Once thicker with black and once thinner on top with another colour.

I have created a simple drop-in replacement of MKPolylineView which lets you do that: ASPolylineView.

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    UIColor *darker = [UIColor blackColor];
    CGFloat baseWidth = self.lineWidth / zoomScale;

    // draw the dark colour thicker
    CGContextAddPath(context, self.path);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, darker.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, baseWidth * 1.5);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, self.lineCap);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    // now draw the stroke color with the regular width
    CGContextAddPath(context, self.path);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.strokeColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, baseWidth);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, self.lineCap);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:context];
}

- (void)createPath
{
    // turn the polyline into a path

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    BOOL pathIsEmpty = YES;

    for (int i = 0; i < self.polyline.pointCount; i++) {
        CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:self.polyline.points[i]];

        if (pathIsEmpty) {
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
            pathIsEmpty = NO;
        } else {
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, point.x, point.y);
        }
    }

    self.path = path;
}
```

Or you can download code for it from below link https://github.com/nighthawk/ASPolylineView

I have used it and have a look on this screen shot.

[image: Border color of polyline]

Answer (score 1):

I got another method.

If you don't have a coordinates array you can draw two polylines.

Draw a first line of your specific line1_width and after that draw the other line with line2_width = line1_width - 1.0.

This will draw two lines, and of the second line you will see only it's margin, becoming the stroke for the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Rob mentioned, use MKPolygon and MKPolygonRenderer instead of a MKPolyline and MKPolylineRenderer, but also make sure your array of points is in clockwise order. If it's in counter-clockwise order you'll just need to reverse it by calling reverse() on the array.

```
pointsToUse.reverse()
let overlay = MKPolygon(coordinates: &pointsToUse, count: pointsToUse.count)
```