# How to Draw the border color for the PolyLine

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I need to draw the border for the **Polyline** on my `Mapview`

[image]

Here is the screenshot that I need to implement but I am getting the poly line without the border.

[image]

**Code Work:**

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

    MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];

    renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor rle_lightBurGundy];

    renderer.fillColor = [UIColor rle_whiteColor];

    renderer.lineWidth = 4.0;

    return renderer;
}
```

Comment: Please add proper images in your question. See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread [Draw MKPolyline Fill Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915226/draw-mkpolyline-fill-color). **Chandni - Systematix' s answer** is a good way to solve your issue ... you need to make an custom renderer that will draw 2 paths (the border and the main polyline). He linked a github exemple you can check the ASPolylineRenderer.h/.m
**Github link :** https://github.com/nighthawk/ASPolylineView

Comment: Unless you include salient points from the link to your answer, this looks more like a comment.